# Tkinter Window Crashes on Exit

Tags: python, tkinter, exit

I'm having a hard time getting started with Tkinter. All my windows seem to crash on attempting to close. (That is, they return execution in IDLE to the prompt, but the window stays open and the quit button stays pressed. The window is unresponsive and has to be killed manually in Windows.) 
The most straightforward example is from the book 'The Quick Python Book'. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
win = Tk()
b = Button(win, text="Goodbye",command=sys.exit)
b.pack()
mainloop()
```

Python gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Scripts/Quick Python Practice Programs/TKinter Practice.py", line
6, in <module>
    mainloop()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1401, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(msg)
SystemExit
```

I'm calling this from the IDLE shell, and I'm pretty sure it is NOT set to ==No Subprocesses==. I get a ==Restart== when I restart the shell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you try win.mainloop() instead of mainloop()

Comment: Alas, same result. Thanks for the quick answer, though. 
More data: Windows 7, Python 3.2.

Comment: @user1910935 add information to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're seeing something related to running in IDLE -- a standalone Tkinter script won't exhibit this behavior.

Chalk it up as an anomaly when running under IDLE.